# Snapshot not working in google play game service

Tags: android, snapshot, google-play-games

I am using the "Saved Game" feature in google play game services but I encounter the problem that I can't create a snapshot to save my game.

The problem seems to be straight enough - enable the "Saved Game" feature in the Play console. However it is not working - or I am doing it wrong.

Here's my Play console's setting. I try to enable and disable the feature but either worked.

[Play Console's setting picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8csHKUrnjXyVW9BYnBDUUI4ck0/edit?usp=sharing)
(sorry I don't have enough reputation to post images)

Developer's Console setting

drive.google.com/file/d/0B8csHKUrnjXycVluT3lIcmEtMjg/edit?usp=sharing

The error log I got is the following:

```
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use snapshots without enabling the 'Saved Game' feature in the Play console
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1439)
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834):    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IGamesService$Stub$Proxy.e(Unknown Source)
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834):    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.GamesClientImpl.b(Unknown Source)
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834):    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.SnapshotsImpl$2.a(Unknown Source)
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834):    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.SnapshotsImpl$2.a(Unknown Source)
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.a$b.b(Unknown Source)
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.a(Unknown Source)
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.c.b(Unknown Source)
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834):    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.SnapshotsImpl.open(Unknown Source)
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834):    at com.yodawnla.newtechlab.GameScene7$6.doInBackground(GameScene7.java:274)
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834):    at com.yodawnla.newtechlab.GameScene7$6.doInBackground(GameScene7.java:1)
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-08 22:44:09.681: E/AndroidRuntime(26834):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

I think I must be doing something wrong but the error log is leading me to nowhere. Does any one ever successfully implements the new "Saved Game" feature?

edit:
The ["Saved Game"](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames) is recently released and meant to replace the old Cloud Save feature. 
Developer's guide never mention anything about play console...

edit2:
Strange enough, my teammate is able to execute the same code without the exception. The only different thing is our login account - which we are both setup as test account except I am the owner of the developer's account.

I am not sure why this is happening but at least my teammate's account is working and we can test the feature again.

So here is the step to setup "Saved Game" feature:

1. Create the game service in play console
2. Link the service to the game with correct RSA signature and package name
3. Enable the "Saved Game" feature under "Game Details"
4. Make sure your account is in the tester account list
5. If you are the owner of the developer's console, it might not work for some reason.

Comment: What in "Cannot use snapshots without enabling the 'Saved Game' feature in the Play console" is unclear to you?

Comment: Actually it is very unclear to me. Have you refer to my image? I tried both enable and disable the feature in the play console but either work. I was wondering if there's other place I need to set thing up.

Answer (score 5):

Try going to **Game Services** -> **Game details**, then click the link to **API console project** on the bottom of the page - it will open different site. Click **APIs**, then enable two services - **Google Play Game Services** and **Drive API**.

Edit: there is also an option to use saved games API inside developer console itself, it shall be enabled.

[image: Google Play developer console]
[image: Console for configuring web APIs]

Comment: The Drive API and Game Services are both on in my case.

Comment: So how did resolved the issue...please comment